# Rotateing vector on plane in 3D

Tags: java, vector, 3d

I have to define a yellow vector from the picture below. That what I know, is the dark green vector and the vertical plane. The angle between lime and dark green vector is 90 degrees.

What i can do is the equation of plane. And i know the rotation of vector in plane but only in 2D dimensional.

So i figured that if i rotate the dark green vector in this plane by 90 degrees, and than move that new vector by dark green vector i would create lime vector. After that i will add that lime vector and dark green vector to define yellow vector.

At the begining i know dark green vector and our plane.

[Graphical representation of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsMp4.png)

Thank you in advance for Your help

Comment: Does that have anything to do with java? Or with programming itself?

Comment: @Maverick283 - I just need to write it in java :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Rodrigues formula. It's for rotating a vector in 3D.
[image]

Here

- v is the vector you want to rotate.
- k is the unit vector describing the axis of rotation

For more information google for Rodrigues formula, or follow [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)

Or you can use [quaternion rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).
It's been explained nicely in this answer [How does this Quaternion rotation code work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280586/how-does-this-quaternion-rotation-code-work)

Comment: I thing it is not what im searching for.
As i have read Rodrigues' rotation formula rotates v by an angle θ around an axis z by decomposing it into its components parallel and perpendicular to z, and rotating only the perpendicular component. But this rotation isnt in one plane by a point of (0,0,0). What i am searching for is to rotate a plane by point (0,0,0) and get a new rotated vector.